# check if date column in datatable is null

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, datatable, dbnull

```
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
dt.Load(dr)

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

    Dim dob_str As String = ""

    'code to check if row.Field(Of Date)("DOB") is dbnull
    'if not dbnull then dob_str = row.Field(Of Date)("DOB")

Next
```

How do I check if the `Date` type column for each row in the `DataTable` is empty?

I tried

```
    If Not row.Field(Of Date)("DOB") = Nothing Then
        dob_str = row.Field(Of Date)("DOB")
    End If
```

and

```
    Dim nullCheck As Boolean = IsDBNull(row.Field(Of Date)("DOB"))
    If nullCheck = False Then
        dob_str = row.Field(Of Date)("DOB")
    End If
```

but they all resulted in the `Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type.` during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx) type

```
If row.Field(Of Date?)("DOB") IsNot Nothing Then
    dob_str = row.Field(Of Date)("DOB")
End If
```

Or

```
If row.Field(Of Date?)("DOB").HasValue Then
    dob_str = row.Field(Of Date)("DOB")
End If
```

Or use [`IsNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
If Not row.IsNull("DOB") Then
    dob_str = row.Field(Of Date)("DOB")
End If
```

Comment: Should you not use `Is Nothing` rather than `= Nothing`?

Comment: `If Not .... = Nothing` results in a warning message `This expression will always evaluate to Nothing (due to null propagation from the equals operator). To check if the value is null consider using 'Is Nothing'.`

Comment: @j_t_fusion Sorry, it's been a while since I've worked in in VB.NET. Corrected.